# Using html in php

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with this statement:
after this i just get blank page.
so the whole code looks like this :
im tyrying to use html in php and than php again in html:
the whole rest works and if i replace '' with add2.php it works but it writes something before i even pick something

```
    <?php

        function login()
        {
        echo "?";
        }
        $get = $_GET['Login'];
        $get = $_POST['Login'];
        echo $get;
        var_dump($get);

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <?php
        require 'connection.php';
        include 'user_verify.php';
        include 'access_verify.php';
        mysql_select_db("idoctor_db") or die("Bląd podczas wybierania bazy danych");


        $select = 'SELECT * FROM users;';
        $query = mysql_query($select);
        // Ustaw domyślny element; tutaj są ustawione kreseczki, żeby nic nie sugerować ;P
        echo '<form action="'<?php login(); ?>'" method="post">
        Jezyk <select name="Login"><option value="0">------------------</option>';

        while ($language = mysql_fetch_object($query)) 
        {
        echo '<option value="'.$language->Login.'" selected>'.$language->Login.'</option>';
        }

        echo '</form>';

        ?>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML form element doesn't render anything on screen... add some content and you will see it is working.

```
<?php 
function login()
{
echo "?";
}
?>

<?php
echo '<form action="<?php login(); ?>" method="post">';
echo 'Hello World!';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

Make sure your quotes are properly closed too. (I'm not sure if the missing closing single quote in your sample was a copy/paste error or not)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo '<form action="<?php login(); ?>" method="post">
?>
```

Is a syntax error, you forgot the closing single quote and semicolon.

That said, I do not think this code will do what you expect: By using `echo` you will send `"<?php login(); ?>"` to the browser, not run it in the PHP interpreter.

Comment: The form action is parsed in the browser, not on the server, so if your login script is called "login.php" you need to set action="login.php"

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<?php
echo '<form action="<?php login(); ?>" method="post">
?>
```

Should be:

```
<?php
echo "<form action='" . login() . "' method='post'>";
?>
```

But then your login function needs to be fixed because printing out `?` is not going to work.

```
function login()
{
   return "login.php";
}
```